# How to make all the things redirect to https and non-www via .htaccess with a single RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I am looking for something that may be considered the ultimate .htaccess rewrite rule for websites with an SSL and that use non-www (naked) domains.

I am looking for an .htaccess rule that is only *one* RewriteRule instead of others that seem to rely on multiple RewriteRule.

This is a list of various scenarios that should ideally redirect to the proper URL:

1. `http://www.example.com` > `https://example.com` (http www to https non-www)
2. `http://example.com` > `https://example.com` (http non-www to https non-www)
3. `https://www.example.com` > `https://example.com` (https www to https non-www)
4. `https://example.com/tester` > `https://example.com/tester/` (adds trailing slash if missing, so not to allow both URLs to work)
5. `https://example.com/tester//` > `https://example.com/tester/` (strips excess trailing slashes)
6. `http://www.example.com/image.jpg` > `https://example.com/image.jpg` (also catches assets that are accessed directly via URL bar)

In the above examples, I'm trying to find one rule, to rule them all — that will fix slashes at the end of URLs (in the past, I've seen rules that serve both `/tester` and `/tester/` ... when only one should exist).

Other rules I've found work for all the cases above, *except* for files such as images, etc. that are accessed directly via the browser URL bar. In those cases, the redirects did not rewrite the URL. Assets accessed directly via the browser should still rewrite to https with non-www.

- Good example: http://www.freshysites.com/wp-content/uploads/404.png (see how http and www both get redirected to https non-www)
- Bad example: http://www.bizi.fit/media/160px-for-black-background.png (see how there is no redirect happening)

Also, ideally, the `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule` wouldn't need to have the actual domain hard-coded into them.

It probably doesn't matter much in this case, but this rule will be used primarily with WordPress sites hosted on Cloudways.